# Swift Collision Boundary not working

Tags: ios, swift, uikit-dynamics

Swift 2.0, xcode 7, Ios 9

Intention: I want the two squares to drop to the bottom and stay at the bottom of the screen.

What is happening now: There is no error preventing the code from running, the gravity works fine but the collision just seems to be ignored. Thus resulting in the two objects falling through the bottom of the screen.

Note: the subclass is UIView not UIViewController and this view is accessed from a segue.

Many Thanks!

Code :

```
import UIKit

class graphs: UIView {

//create two shapes
var greenSquare: UIView?
var redSquare: UIView?
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    var dimen = CGRectMake(25, 25, 60, 60)
    greenSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    greenSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    dimen = CGRectMake(130, 25, 90, 90)
    redSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    redSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //add them to the screen
    self.addSubview(greenSquare!)
    self.addSubview(redSquare!)

}

@IBAction func startbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
     //initialise the animator
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator()

    //colision
    let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items:[greenSquare!,redSquare!])
    boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

    //add gravity
    let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!])
    let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0)
    gravity.gravityDirection = direction

    animator?.addBehavior(boundries)
    animator?.addBehavior(gravity)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the subclass to a UIViewController

why did the previous code not work?

this is the new code:

```
import UIKit

class DrawView: UIViewController {

//Create two shapes
var greenSquare: UIView?
var redSquare: UIView?
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func startbutton(sender: UIButton) {

    //Create the shapes
    var dimen = CGRectMake(25, 25, 60, 60)
    greenSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    greenSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    dimen = CGRectMake(130, 25, 90, 90)
    redSquare = UIView(frame: dimen)
    redSquare?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    //Add them to the screen
    self.view.addSubview(greenSquare!)
    self.view.addSubview(redSquare!)

    //Initialize the animator
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)

    //Gravity
    let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!] )
    let direction = CGVectorMake(0.0, 1.0)
    gravity.gravityDirection = direction

    //Collision
    let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!] )
    boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

    //Elasticity
    let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [greenSquare!, redSquare!] )
    bounce.elasticity = 0.5

    animator?.addBehavior(bounce)
    animator?.addBehavior(boundries)
    animator?.addBehavior(gravity)
    }

}
```